# Read Excel Cell And Set Row Colour

Tags: c#, excel, com, interop

I am using Com Interop and C#.  I have to iterate through an Excel file looking for certain values in each of the rows (always in column 2).  For some values I need to set the background colour of the row to red.

I am having trouble:

1. Reading the value in cell [i][2] for row i, and
2. Setting the background colour of this row.

Basically I am looking for something like this (which is the best I can find after much Googling):

```
// ws is the worksheet
for (int i = 1; i <= ws.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    Range range = ws.Cells[i][2];
    int count = Convert.ToInt32(range.Value2.ToString());
    if (count >= 3)
    {
        Range chronic = ws.UsedRange.Rows[i];
        chronic.EntireRow.Cells.Interior.Color = 0xFF0000;
    }
}
```

Of course this doesn't work.  I can't get past the first hurdle of just reading the cell.  Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: `ws.UsedRange.Rows[i];` should be `ws.Rows[i];` Usedrange doesn't always begin on the first row. And `Cells[i][2]` should be `Cells[i,2]`

Comment: Is there a reason you have to do this with another program instead of using the conditional formatting already built into Excel? You probably can add a conditional format with inter-op, though I'm not familiar enough with inter-op to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. The code *assumes* that the value in the column 2 cell is a number.

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using System.Reflection;

Missing noValue = Missing.Value;
Excel.Range conditionalCell;
foreach (Excel.Range usedRange in ws.UsedRange.Rows)
{
    conditionalCell = usedRange.Cells[noValue, 2] as Excel.Range;
    if (Convert.ToInt32(conditionalCell.Value2) >= 3)
    {
        usedRange.Cells.Interior.Color = Excel.XlRgbColor.rgbRed;
    }
}
```